# Which features does SQL Server need for SharePoint 2007

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007

The title says it, I searched the net but not even in the microsoft technet they mention what features I must activate for SQL Server 2005. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database. That is all - for the core functionality. No additional services needed.